# Has anyone achieved to embed an interactive 3D model into a PDF with Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, 3d

I've stumbled upon some 3D models embedded in a PDF, e.g. http://cic.nist.gov/vrml/cis/DesignData3.pdf However, with the recent adobe reader I am able to watch such PDFs and also view interactively at those 3D models. So the question is: could I generate such nice PDF with Ubuntu too? TexLive?

Comment: Apparently its a embedded file (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_3D), so you would need to export to the u3d file first

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much about this, but from what I've found, looks like you can. First you have to convert your 3D object to Universal 3D format(`.u3d`) and then use `TexLive` to embed that object into Tex file, finally you have to compile it to PDF with the help of a package called `movie15`.

Here is a [tool/tutorial](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jreality/mediawiki/index.php/Export_U3D_files) for exporting to u3d and embedding it to PDF. MeshLab can also be used for converting to u3d.